# log remote errors using spawn and expect in bash script

Tags: git, bash, shell, expect

i am currently working on the expect script to push the data from git repository to other server.but i want to log the error message that comes from the remote repository.

here is the following code line for the spawn.

```
spawn git push --force user@ip:/var/git/repo.git master 2> >(tee /home/user/error.log >&2)
```

but this above code doesnt work and it throws an error :

```
error: src refspec 2> does not match any.
error: src refspec >(tee does not match any.
error: src refspec /home/user/error.log does not match any.
error: src refspec >&2) does not match any.
```

i have also tried :

```
$(spawn git push --force user@ip:/var/git/repo.git) > /home/user/output.log
```

but it is still not working.

My main motive here, is to log the error message that i get from the remote repository and display them to the output screen as well.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
 when using the "glenn jackman" answer it logs everything, the echo message as well as error message, but i only the error message to be logged.

```
remote: changing directory to the one which is not available
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 5: cd: someunknown: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why use expect for this?

Comment: its pretty simple, to pass the password automatically when pushing to the remote servers, i have few of the servers and want to push them all, and i have made this script asynchronous so that i will execute the script from my localmachine and the script gets executed on one of the server and this script in turn pushes to all the servers that i have and on completion , send me an email with the error.log if there is any errors.

Answer (score 0):

expect does not understand bash process substitution syntax. If you want it specifically, you need to spawn bash to execute it:

```
spawn bash -c {git push --force user@ip:/var/git/repo.git master 2> >(tee /home/user/error.log >&2)}
```

Note the use of braces: expect's braces act like the shell's single quotes: group some words as a single string with no variable or command interpolation.

Comment: but this seems to be logging everything , but i just want the errors messages from the remote repository... but this logs the echo message as well as error message -- "remote: changing directory to the one which is not available
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 5: cd: someunknown: No such file or directory"

Comment: maybe you want `git push ... 2>&1 1>/dev/null` instead